# system suspend - dbus upower signals are not seen

Tags: systemd, suspend, dbus

I want to get notifications via dbus when the system resumes from suspended state.
Following these existing questions:

1. [What DBus signal is sent on system suspend?](https://serverfault.com/questions/191381/what-dbus-signal-is-sent-on-system-suspend/210687#210687)
2. [How do I detect when my system wakes up from suspend via DBus or similar in a python app?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183516/how-do-i-detect-when-my-system-wakes-up-from-suspend-via-dbus-or-similar-in-a-py)

But none of the examples found in the links above fire when I suspend or resume.
*dbus-monitor* does not see anything either:

```
 dbus-monitor --system "type='signal',interface='org.freedesktop.UPower'"
```

I also tried using this code to fire the signal manually (easier):

```
#taken from /usr/lib/systemd/system/upower.service
dbus-send --system --type=signal --dest=org.freedesktop.UPower \
    /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Resuming
```

Same result. I must be missing something really obvious.
Fedora 20 x86_64. (dbus is installed, running and working fine AFAICT)
Fedora 20 uses [logind](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind/), but I cannot see any 'Resuming' signal there.
Suspend and resume is difficult to test with VirtualBox, so I can't really compare with other OSes.

Interestingly, qdbus sees lots of services (org.gnome.SessionManager, etc..) , but nothing power related, but then again, it doesn't see login1 either..

```
qdbus | grep -i power | wc -l
0
```

Comment: I don't think upower handles suspend and resume anymore; http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/devkit-devel/2013-January/001339.html

Comment: @sciurus ok, so how am I supposed to get notification of "Resuming"? (will update the question to make it clearer this is what I want, upower or not) It is odd that the systemd service file is present and is meant to fire "Resuming" still, is it not?

Comment: I could be wrong, of course. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this answer](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/devkit-devel/2014-March/001575.html) to the same question on the devkit mailing list used by [upower](http://upower.freedesktop.org/), newer versions *no longer emit that signal since this handled by systemd*.

The replacement in systemd-land is [logind](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind/), which has a signal called *PrepareForSleep*:
*"The PrepareForShutdown() resp. PrepareForSleep() signals are sent right before (with the argument True) and after (with the argument False) the system goes down for reboot/poweroff, resp. suspend/hibernate."*

Here is a simple python script for watching suspend / resume events:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from datetime import datetime
import dbus
import gobject
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

def handle_sleep(*args):
    print "%s    PrepareForSleep%s" % (datetime.now().ctime(), args)

DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)     # integrate into gobject main loop
bus = dbus.SystemBus()                 # connect to system wide dbus
bus.add_signal_receiver(               # define the signal to listen to
    handle_sleep,                      # callback function
    'PrepareForSleep',                 # signal name
    'org.freedesktop.login1.Manager',  # interface
    'org.freedesktop.login1'           # bus name
)

loop = gobject.MainLoop()
loop.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer helped me a lot! But in case someone needs a Qt version...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from datetime import datetime
import sys, dbus
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from dbus.mainloop.qt import DBusQtMainLoop

class DBusListener():

  def handle_sleep(self, suspended):
    print(datetime.now().ctime()," Suspended? ", str(suspended))

  def __init__(self):
    DBusQtMainLoop(set_as_default=True)    # integrate into Qt main loop
    bus = dbus.SystemBus()                 # connect to system wide dbus
    bus.add_signal_receiver(               # define the signal to listen to
      self.handle_sleep,                   # callback function
      'PrepareForSleep',                   # signal name
      'org.freedesktop.login1.Manager',    # interface
      'org.freedesktop.login1'             # bus name
    )

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
DBusListener()
app.exec_()
```